# Rails 500 Internal Server Error ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm running Rails on Nginx and 5 Thin web servers.  It keeps hanging !!

I'm getting a 500 Internal Server Error. But, I don't understand what's causing it.

`My questions are:`

1) How can I figure out what is causing the problem?  What steps do I take?

2) Is the page `index8` causing the problem?  (It's a dataTable using ajax calls - json)

3) Would 500 errors `hang` the system?  Or am I just assuming that they are the cause?

Error Log:

Started GET "/workorders/index8?sEcho=1&iColumns=10&sColumns=&iDisplayStart=0&iDisplayLength=10&mDataProp_0=0&mDataProp_1=1&mDataProp_2=2&mDataProp_3=3&mDataProp_4=4&mDataProp_5=5&mDataProp_6=6&mDataProp_7=7&mDataProp_8=8&mDataProp_9=9&sSearch=&bRegex=false&sSearch_0=&bRegex_0=false&bSearchable_0=true&sSearch_1=&bRegex_1=false&bSearchable_1=true&sSearch_2=&bRegex_2=false&bSearchable_2=true&sSearch_3=&bRegex_3=false&bSearchable_3=true&sSearch_4=&bRegex_4=false&bSearchable_4=true&sSearch_5=&bRegex_5=false&bSearchable_5=true&sSearch_6=&bRegex_6=false&bSearchable_6=true&sSearch_7=&bRegex_7=false&bSearchable_7=true&sSearch_8=&bRegex_8=false&bSearchable_8=true&sSearch_9=&bRegex_9=false&bSearchable_9=true&iSortCol_0=0&sSortDir_0=asc&iSortingCols=1&bSortable_0=true&bSortable_1=true&bSortable_2=true&bSortable_3=true&bSortable_4=true&bSortable_5=true&bSortable_6=true&bSortable_7=true&bSortable_8=true&bSortable_9=true&_=1378992988374" for 198.50.4.4 at 2013-09-12 07:40:32 -0600
Processing by WorkordersController#index8 as JSON
  Parameters: {"sEcho"=>"1", "iColumns"=>"10", "sColumns"=>"", "iDisplayStart"=>"0", "iDisplayLength"=>"10", "mDataProp_0"=>"0", "mDataProp_1"=>"1", "mDataProp_2"=>"2", "mDataProp_3"=>"3", "mDataProp_4"=>"4", "mDataProp_5"=>"5", "mDataProp_6"=>"6", "mDataProp_7"=>"7", "mDataProp_8"=>"8", "mDataProp_9"=>"9", "sSearch"=>"", "bRegex"=>"false", "sSearch_0"=>"", "bRegex_0"=>"false", "bSearchable_0"=>"true", "sSearch_1"=>"", "bRegex_1"=>"false", "bSearchable_1"=>"true", "sSearch_2"=>"", "bRegex_2"=>"false", "bSearchable_2"=>"true", "sSearch_3"=>"", "bRegex_3"=>"false", "bSearchable_3"=>"true", "sSearch_4"=>"", "bRegex_4"=>"false", "bSearchable_4"=>"true", "sSearch_5"=>"", "bRegex_5"=>"false", "bSearchable_5"=>"true", "sSearch_6"=>"", "bRegex_6"=>"false", "bSearchable_6"=>"true", "sSearch_7"=>"", "bRegex_7"=>"false", "bSearchable_7"=>"true", "sSearch_8"=>"", "bRegex_8"=>"false", "bSearchable_8"=>"true", "sSearch_9"=>"", "bRegex_9"=>"false", "bSearchable_9"=>"true", "iSortCol_0"=>"0", "sSortDir_0"=>"asc", "iSortingCols"=>"1", "bSortable_0"=>"true", "bSortable_1"=>"true", "bSortable_2"=>"true", "bSortable_3"=>"true", "bSortable_4"=>"true", "bSortable_5"=>"true", "bSortable_6"=>"true", "bSortable_7"=>"true", "bSortable_8"=>"true", "bSortable_9"=>"true", "_"=>"1378992988374"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 6125ms

UPDATE1

I'm thinking now that the 500 error is not hanging the system.  I went back through the log and see it showing up when the system is not hanging.

So, I'm back to square one.  How can I determine what is causing the hang?

(Of course, I have a second problem - why am I getting 500 errors anyway?)

Comment: Remove the backtrace silencers. Are you sure the "system is hung"? That it returned an error status implies it's not hung.

Comment: If the 500 error is not telling me what is hanging the system, what do I do to find out the cause?

Comment: @Reddirt: use a debugger and go line after line through `index8` method so you will see what's going on.

Comment: I don't know what "backtrace silencers" are.  I searched my Rails app code and didn't find those words.  Where do I look?

Comment: I found initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb - But, it just has comments in it.

Comment: @Reddirt Right. See the one where it comments out the line that removes the backtrace silencers? Uncomment that. Restart. Run. See if the output is different.

Comment: @Reddirt Please use `@` responses or the person you're replying to may not be notified.